# External definition for identifier with internal linkage

Tags: c, c99, linkage

I've read the following rule in C99 standard 6.9.3

> There shall be no more than one external definition for each identifier declared with internal linkage in a translation unit. Moreover, if an identifier declared with internal linkage is used in an expression (other than as a part of the operand of a sizeof operator whose result is an integer constant), there shall be exactly one external definition for the identifier in the translation unit.

My questions:

(1) What exactly is an external definition?

(2) Why the following code does not violate this rule?

```
static int a = 1;

int main()
{
    a += 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: C standard since ca. 5 years is C11, not C99. Unless you have to maintain some old code, you should use the current (and only) standard. About your question: That will be answered in any good C book. What did you try to find out yourself? Why do you think/which arguments do you have it _does_ violate the rule? And did you read what the `static` _storage class specifier_ implies? There is no external definition shown, except for `main`.

Comment: @Olaf If you've actually read both standards, they have the same words in the same section for this question. So why bother it's C99 or C11? "There is no external definition shown, except for main." That's exactly my question, if you've seriously read it.

Comment: @Olaf And about what I did to find out the answer myself. I don't quite understand the difference between external definition and external linkage, and I googled the term with no useful result. I have actually read some good C books. I just don't understand the terms and language used in the standard. Satisfied?

Comment: @Olaf your comment is hostile, irrelevant and wrong.  You berate someone for posting on here instead of reading a book, but then show your own lack of knowledge on the topic. (`static int a = 1;` is an external definition). You look pretty foolish right now. Please be more polite in future and consider whether your comment will actually be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that you are confusing external definition with the definition that uses `extern` keyword.

The definition is written in both C99/C11 in the semantics part of 6.9:

> These are described as ‘‘external’’ because  they appear  outside  any
>   function  (and  hence  have  file  scope).

In your example, the code does not violate the rule, because you have exactly one external defintion of object with internal linkage, that is:

```
static int a = 1;
```